# WooCommerce RestAPI - OrderUpdate PUT not working in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to update the STATUS of a Woocommerce order using the RestAPI in VB.NET
It works in postman, but I can not figure out what is wrong in .NET

Here is my code:

```
    Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls Or Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 Or Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

    Dim client = New RestClient("https://staging3.reekooz.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders/227175")
    Dim request = New RestRequest(Method.PUT)
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic correctString")
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain")
    Dim qu As String = Chr(34)
    Dim txt As String = "{" & qu & "status" & qu & ": " & qu & "preparing" & qu & "}"
    Response.Write(txt & br & br & br)
    request.AddParameter("application/json,text/plain", txt, ParameterType.RequestBody)
    Dim r = client.Execute(request)
    Response.Write(r.Content)
```

HERE is the C# Rest from Postman's (working version)

```
var client = new RestClient("https://staging3.reekooz.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders/227175");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.PUT);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic correct string");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
request.AddParameter("application/json,text/plain", "{\n  \"status\": \"preparing\"\n}",  ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

The connection takes place and my response has the entire order, but the status is not updated to preparing. (Yes, preparing is added as a custom status, and as I said, this works in Postman)

Comment: I'd recommend to escape quotes using two quote marks sequentially, i.e. `""`, instead of using the character code (though I wouldn't expect it to have an impact).  You also omitted the newlines that are in the C# (shouldn't make a difference in the validity of the json but it's a difference between the two).  Any particular reason you omitted the timeout setting in the VB?

Comment: Had the timeout but also didn't work

Comment: @Yoni do you have postman collection for woocommerce rest api? in mine add product is not working but get is working..